# c#: get nested message from protobuf

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to get a nested message from an empty protobuf message.
for some reason, I keep getting null.

```
public IMessage GetSubMessage(object message /*which is a specific protobuf message*/, string sub /*a property name*/)
{
    if (message == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(message));
    var typ = message.GetType();

    var member = typ.GetProperty(sub);
    // member contains correct field descriptor
    var su = member.GetValue(message) as IMessage;
    // su is null
    return (IMessage)su;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Null is possible, because submessage is not changed (is not set any value inside submessage). Explicit set one of value or you can see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64481478/2050745) of dealing with submessages.